# xml rpc request error

Tags: iphone, xml, xml-parsing, xml-rpc

In iphone I try to connect I am getting the following error:

Content-Type must be 'text/xml,' 'multipart/*,' 'application/soap+xml,' 'or 'application/dime' instead of 'text/xml,application/xml'

It connects to many bugzilla sites but for one bugzilla site it gives me the above error.

Kindly help me out.

Thanks